# sounds are not being played in my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an app that should play 3 distinct sounds and I define them as so in my ViewDidLoad:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2357_02" ofType:@"m4a"]], &addedSound);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2357_01" ofType:@"m4a"]], &updatedSound);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"notifier_12" ofType:@"m4a"]], &notFoundSound);
```

And I cue them to play like so:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(addedSound);
```

They play in the simulator but not on the ipad?  In my Build Phases under Copy Bundle Resources I see them listed so I assumed that they should make it as part of my app - what am I missing here?

Comment: Hate to state the obvious, but you're sure the device isn't set to mute? It's a silly thing but I forget to check it once and pounded my head for a few minutes...

Comment: Dupe? Is your sound too long: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014578/sound-on-simulator-but-not-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually used the solution suggested by Tammenn on this question and it worked great for me:
[Sound on simulator but not device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014578/sound-on-simulator-but-not-device)