# Playing sound on iPad, using AudioToolbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I found a function to play sounds using toolbox, creds going to whomever created it:

```
-(SystemSoundID) createSoundID: (NSString*)name {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@",
             [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], name];

    NSURL* filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path isDirectory: NO];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", path, filePath);
    return soundID;
}
```

However once I want the sound the play and I use the function

```
mySound = [self createSoundID: @"canopen.wav"];

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
```

It only plays in the simulator and not once I move it over to the iPad. Please help

Comment: Could it be that your iPad is muted?

Comment: Dupe? Is your sound too long? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014578/sound-on-simulator-but-not-device

Comment: YES!! haha the sound was on but the button on the side was switched down! xD Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me a while ago. Check whether your iPad is muted :)