# Best ways to play simple sound effect in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm finding a number of conflicting data about playing sounds in iOS. What is a recommended way to play just a simple "ping" sound bite every time the user touches the screen?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the best way of playing a simple sound in iOS (no more than 30 seconds):

```
//Retrieve audio file
NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundeffect" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath : path];

SystemSoundID audioEffect;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);

// call the following function when the sound is no longer used
// (must be done AFTER the sound is done playing)
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(audioEffect);
```

Comment: To completed this, Add this AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion for playing complete notification and this AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion for unregister notification.

Comment: This code does not compile in ARC. I added the "__bridge" to fix: AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);

Answer (score 29):

I use this:

**Header file:**

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

@interface SoundEffect : NSObject
{
    SystemSoundID soundID;
}

- (id)initWithSoundNamed:(NSString *)filename;
- (void)play;

@end
```

**Source file:**

```
#import "SoundEffect.h"

@implementation SoundEffect

- (id)initWithSoundNamed:(NSString *)filename
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:filename withExtension:nil];
        if (fileURL != nil)
        {
            SystemSoundID theSoundID;
            OSStatus error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, &theSoundID);
            if (error == kAudioServicesNoError)
                soundID = theSoundID;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
}

- (void)play
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

@end
```

You will need to create an instance of SoundEffect and direct call the method play on it.

Comment: This is great. I was using C arrays of SystemSoundIDs, but I just hit a point where that was way too much schlepp to deal with. Switching to something based on this. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work with ARC though. For using it with ARC you have to add a completion callback function, where you dispose the systemsound. If you do this in dealloc the sound is killed immediately:
`AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, NULL, NULL, completionCallback, (__bridge_retained void *)self);`
Like this for Example

Comment: @Maverick1st This works perfectly well with ARC, you just have to make sure your `SoundEffect` object doesn't get deallocated immediately, such as by assigning it to a property.

Answer (score 10):

(Small amendment to the correct answer to take care of the disposing of the audio)

```
NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundeffect" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath : path];

SystemSoundID audioEffect;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
// Using GCD, we can use a block to dispose of the audio effect without using a NSTimer or something else to figure out when it'll be finished playing.
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(30 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(audioEffect);
});
```

Comment: This is the best way to play sound asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AVFoundation` or `AudioToolbox`.

Here're two examples which use the libraries separately.

- [SAMSoundEffect](https://github.com/soffes/SAMSoundEffect) (archived repository)
- [BRYSoundEffectPlayer](https://github.com/irace/BRYSoundEffectPlayer)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated answer for Swift (4):

```
import AudioToolbox

func playSound() {
    var soundId: SystemSoundID = 0
    guard let soundPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Success7", withExtension: "wav") else {
        print("Error finding file")
        return
    }

    let error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundPath as CFURL, &soundId)
    if error != kAudioServicesNoError {
        print("Error loading sound")
        return
    }

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(soundId) {
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundId)
    }
}
```

If you have a sound effect that you want to play multiple times in a view, then you can be a little more smart about loading and disposing of the audio:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate lazy var soundId: SystemSoundID? = {
        guard let soundPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Success7", withExtension: "wav") else {
            return nil
        }

        var soundId: SystemSoundID = 0
        let error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundPath as CFURL, &soundId)
        if error != kAudioServicesNoError {
            return nil
        }

        return soundId
    }()

    func playScannedSound() {
        guard let soundId = self.soundId else {
            return
        }

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(soundId, nil)
    }

    deinit {
        guard let soundId = self.soundId else {
            return
        }
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundId)
    }

}
```