# AVAudioPlayer looped sound oddities

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I'm using this code to load and begin playing a sound:

```
- (void) buzz {
    if (buzzSound == nil) {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

        NSError *error;
        NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSURL *soundFile = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: [mainBundle pathForResource: @"buzzer_8"
                                                                                    ofType: @"wav"]];
        buzzSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: soundFile error: &error];
        buzzSound.delegate = self;

        if (DEBUG_BLE && error != nil)
            printf("Error loading sound: %s\n", [[error localizedDescription] cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }

    // Play the sound.
    buzzSound.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [buzzSound prepareToPlay];
    [buzzSound setVolume: 1.0];
    if (![buzzSound play]) {
        self.buzzSound = nil;
        [self buzzSound];
    }
}
```

This code is triggered by a touch down event on a button. When the button gets a touch up event (on or off of the button), it stops the sound with:

```
    [buzzSound stop];
```

The buzz sound itself is a short .wav file.

1. The first time buzz is called, the sound plays once. It does not repeat. On subsequent calls it does repeat. Why?
2. Intermittently, if I play the sound for a short period of time that is about the same length of time as one cycle through the sound file, the sound fails on subsequent calls to buzz, and play returns NO. Thereafter, play will always return NO until the sound is reloaded, after which is plays  the sound once as noted above and then starts working correctly until the sound is played for a short time, again.

I do have audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:error: set up; no error is reported.

Comment: Note: I do not see this problem using a longer sound file. It only happens on the short sound designed to repeat.

Comment: I faced a similar problem once before, perhaps you could try using this answer, as it's a better approach for these types of short sounds: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9791649/3704795