# Trouble playing simple sound effect in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

Trying to implement a simple sound effect to play in background of app. Code is based on answer here: [Best way to play simple sound effect in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791491/best-way-to-play-simple-sound-effect-in-ios).

```c
 - (void) viewDidLoad {
       NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"poke_sound" ofType:@"mp3"];

       NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath : path];

       SystemSoundID audioEffect;

       AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) CFBridgingRetain(pathURL), &audioEffect);

       AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);

}
```

Noise will not play when I run app in simulator. Thanks for the help!

**Note:** I'm using xcode 6 beta, so who knows what bugs could pop up there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't play an MP3 with Audio Services. You can only play CAF, AIF, or WAV. But you can play MP3 with `AVAudioPlayer` for instance. Check out this article for more info: http://www.raywenderlich.com/69369/audio-tutorial-ios-playing-audio-programatically-2014-edition