# How can I add some sound effect to my music in ios?

Tags: ios, audio, channel, effect

Such as the left channel sounds louder, and the other sounds small..
I search a lot about that, but nothing useful got.QAQ
Some questions I found like this [Recommended way to play simple sound effect in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791491/best-way-to-play-simple-sound-effect-in-ios)

But when I tried, I got a warning
`21:05:18.887 WARNING:  998: Failure to setup sound, err = -50`
I guess this is not I want, because I didn't found a 'effect setting' code in there.