# System Sound plays in iPhone simulator but on iphone not playing

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to play a system sound on my iphone, the sound plays very well in the simulator but on the device doesn't work.

```
- (IBAction)SystemSound:(id)sender {
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"waterfall"      ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundFileURL, &systemSound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSound);
}
```

Comment: Some audio files only work on the simulator. Does yours follow the correct [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4194480/193896)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a small detail that many developers have wasted hours upon:

### Case Sensitivity

Really, it all boils down to:

- iPhone **Simulator**: Case-**Insensitive**
- iOS **device**: Case-**Sensitive**

So, you might have 'waterfall' in your code, but the actual sound name is 'Waterfall'. It might even be something like 'wAtErFaLl'.

This will work fine on the simulator, but **not** on the device - the device simply won't find the sound.

This has happened to me for everything from sounds to images to plists.

### Check your Cases!

Also, AudioServices has some [guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) on what can play in the device and what can't:

> Sound files that you play using this function must be: - **No longer than 30 seconds** in duration - In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) format - **Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or .wav file**

Comment: i have checked all the specifications of System Sound Services and my sound is no longer than 30 seconds, is packaged in .caf and is linear PCM, i don't know yet why is not playing on my device. Also i have checked the sound name and is waterfall.caf. This sound works perfectly in AVAudio player but not in Systemsound

Comment: @CarlosVela Why not use AVAudioPlayer then?

Comment: I know this is old, but sometimes we tend to miss the most obvious steps. I had the same problem, until I realized that I forgot to add the sound to my target.

Answer (score 7):

Couple other things to check before chasing the code issues listed above:

1) Is your phone paired with a Bluetooth headset?  If so, the audio will come out there instead of your external speaker.

2) Is your audio muted? Check the switch on the side and your settings.

Comment: LOL that was my problem too. I forgot the silent switch overrides some app sounds.

Comment: My audio was muted. Thank you.